# c++ sort function of List

Tags: c++, sorting

My sort function looks like this:

```
template <typename Compare, typename T>    
void List<T>::sort(const Compare& comparer){   
...   
}
```

But I received next error:

> template definition of non-template
>   `void List<T>::sort(const Compare&)'
>
>   invalid use of undefined type`class
>   List'

What does it mean?

This is the complete code of the list:

```
template <typename T> class Node;    
template <typename T> class Iterator;    
template <typename T>    
class List{     
private:    
    Node<T> * first;     
    Node<T> * last;    
    int size;    
    friend class Predicate ;    
    friend class Compare;    
public:    
    typedef Iterator<T> iterator;    

    List(){    
       first = NULL;    
       last = NULL;    
       size = 0;    
    }    
    List(const List<T> & l);    
    void pushBack(T element);    
    void insert( const T& element, iterator i);    
    iterator remove(iterator i);    
    iterator find(const Predicate& predicate);    
    void sort(const Compare& comparer);    
    int getSize() const;    
    iterator begin();    
    iterator end();    
    ~List();    
};    

template <class T>    
List<T>::List(const List & l) {    
    first = 0;    
    last = 0;    
    size = 0;    
    for (Node<T> * current = l.first; current != 0; current = current -> next){
        pushBack(current -> data);    
    }    
}    

template <typename T>    
void List<T>::pushBack(T element){    
   Node<T>* newnode = new Node<T>(element);    
   if (newnode->prev == NULL) {    
      first = newnode;    
      last = newnode;    
   }else{    
      newnode->prev = last;    
      last->next = newnode;    
      last = newnode;    
   }    
}    

template <typename T>    
void List<T>::insert( const T& element, iterator i){    
   if (i.position == NULL){    
      pushBack(element);    
      ++size;    
      return;    
   }    
   Node<T>* after = i.position;    
   Node<T>* before =  after->prev;    
   Node<T>* newnode = new Node<T>(element);    
   newnode->prev = before;    
   newnode->next = after;    
   after->prev = newnode;    
   if (before == NULL) {    
      first = newnode;    
   }    
   else{    
      before->next = newnode;    
   }    
   ++size;    
}    

template <typename T>    
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::remove(iterator iter){    
      if(iter.position != NULL){    
          Node<T>* remove = iter.position;    
           Node<T>* before = remove->prev;    
           Node<T>* after = remove->next;    
           if (remove == first){    
               first = after;    
           } else{    
               before->next = after;    
           }    
           if (remove == last){    
               last = before;    
           }else{    
               after->prev = before;    
           }    
           iter.position = after;    
           --size;    
           delete remove;    
           return iter;    
      }else{    
       throw ElementNotFound();    
   }    
}    

template <typename T>    
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin(){    
   //iterator iter;    
   //iter.position = first;    
   //iter.last = last;    
    return iterator(first);    
}    

template <typename T>    
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end(){    
     return iterator (last);    
}    


template <typename Predicate, typename T>    
List<T>::iterator List<T>::find(const Predicate& predicate){    
    iterator iter;    
    for( iter = begin(); iter != end(); iter = next()){    
        if( predicate(iter.getElement())){    
            return iter;    
        }    
    }    
    return end();    
}    

template <typename Compare, typename T>    
void List<T>::sort(const Compare& comparer){    
    Iterator<T> iter;    
    for( iter = begin(); iter != end(); iter = iter.next() ){    
        if( comparer( iter.getElement() , (iter+1).getElement()) != true){    

        }    
    }    
}    

template <typename T>    
int List<T>::getSize() const{    
    return size;    
}    

template <class T>    
List <T>::~List() {    
    Node <T> * firstNode = first;    
    while (firstNode != 0)     {    
        Node <T> * nextNode = firstNode->next;    
        delete firstNode;    
        firstNode = nextNode;    
    }    
}    
template <typename T> class Node {    
private:    
    T data;    
    Node* next;    
    Node* prev;    
    friend class List<T>;    
    friend class Iterator<T>;    
public:    
    Node(T element){    
        data = element;    
        prev = NULL;    
        next = NULL;    
    }    
    ~Node(){}    
};    

template <typename T> class Iterator{    
private:    
   Node<T>* position;    
   Node<T>* last;    
   friend class List<T>;    
public:     
   Iterator(){    
       position = NULL;    
       last = NULL;    
   }    
   Iterator(Node<T> * source): position(source) { }    
   T& getElement()const;    
   bool operator==(Iterator b) const;    
   bool operator!=(Iterator b) const;    
   T & operator*();    
   Iterator & operator++();    
   Iterator & operator++(int);    
   ~Iterator(){}    
};    

template <class T>    
T& Iterator<T>::getElement() const{    
   if(position != NULL){     
       return position->data;    
   }    
   else{    
       throw ElementNotFound();    
   }    
}    

template <typename T>    
bool Iterator<T>::operator==(Iterator b) const{    
   return position == b.position;    
}    

template <typename T>    
bool Iterator<T>::operator!=(Iterator b) const{    
    return position != b.position;    
}    

template <typename T>    
T & Iterator<T>::operator*() {    
    return position->data;    
}    

template <class T>    
Iterator<T> & Iterator<T>::operator++() {    
    position = position->next;    
    return *this;    
}    

template <class T>    
Iterator<T> & Iterator<T>::operator++(int){    
    position = position->next;    
    return *this;    
}    


#endif /* LISTGENERIC_H_ */
```

Comment: format this better, and add the full failing code.

Comment: Why not use `std::list`, which comes with a sort function.

Comment: I am trying to build my own list container

Comment: Is there a particular reason why *every d--n line* in your code has four pending white spaces?

Answer (score 4):

Either you declare `sort` as a **template function** with one template argument (`Compare`) inside the class. Then your definition has to look as follows:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename Compare>
void List<T>::sort(const Compare& comparer) {
    …
}
```

And you also need to remove the now redundant `friend class Compare` declaration from your `List` class.

**Or** you keep `Compare` and `sort` as-is. In this case, simply don’t have `sort` as a template, and omit the `Compare` template argument:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::sort(const Compare& comparer) {
    …
}
```

Of course this only works if you have *defined* (not just declared!) the class `Compare` before this function.

But this second solution would be highly unorthodox and pretty useless since the `compare` argument doesn’t make much sense: there is only *one* `Compare` class and the user cannot change it. Normally, this *should* be a template argument (first solution).

Comment: Why did you gave the template parameters `T` and `Compare` into separate lines of code (with separate angle brackets)?

Comment: @ChristianAmmer Separate angle brackets: because that’s required – these are two *separate* templates, after all: one concerning the class, and one concerning the method. That’s the whole crux of the question. Separate lines: for readability.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Ahh I see, thanks for the further explanation.

Comment: I recieved: 
invalid function declaration    
no member function `sort' declared in `List<T>'
about the line void List<T>::sort(const Compare& comparer) {

Comment: @user808176 Well the message really tells you everything that you need to know: you haven’t declared a matching function `sort` inside your class. In fact, you have forgotten to provide the template argument `Compare` in the declaration of the function.

Comment: Is It not enough to declare  friend class Compare; in the List class?

Comment: @user808176 Only if `Compare` isn’t a template argument. Then the simple solution is to remove the template argument from your `sort` implementation also. But you cannot simply interchange classes and template arguments, they are not the same thing.

Comment: But the class is template only if it is declered as 
template <typename T> class Compare; and it does not.Am I right?

Comment: @user808176 You are confusing classes, class templates, and template *arguments*. I’ll update my answer …